# XMPP Server on EC2 Amazon Web Service (AWS)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, xmpp, openfire

My company uses OpenFire for server-side and smack for client-side in its XMPP Android application.

AWS seems like a good and scalable service for what we need. 
We use it for testing our app, but I'm afraid that the server will crash with 20k-50k users.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is AWS good enough for an XMPP (OpenFire) server? What are the pros and cons?
2. How do I build such an application that can handle 20k online users at least, and lets say 2k opened chat rooms?
3. Is there any specific tutorial for this kind of stuff?

Money is not a problem in terms of server costs. Time is what matter for us right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved to ServerFault:
https://serverfault.com/questions/229039/xmpp-server-on-ec2-amazon-web-service-aws